# Kendo UI grid binding error

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am working with kendo UI grid here is my code

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
 $("#logs").kendoGrid({
                    dataSource: {
                        type: "json",
                        transport: {
                            read: {
                                url: "https://localhost:1153/v3.svc/auditlog",
                                dataType: "json",
                                data: '?&tableName=' + table + '&userId=' + userId + '&fromDate=' + dateFrom + '&toDate=' + dateto + '&isSearchForClient=' + true,
                                type: "GET",
                                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
                            }
                        },
                        pageSize: 10, //page size
                        schema: {
                            data: "d", //root element that contains data array
                            total: "d.length" //total amount of records
                        }
                    },
                    pageable: true, //enable paging
                    columns: [{ field: "d.TransactionId", title: "TransactionID", width: "30px" }, { field: "d.Log", title: "Audit Logs", width: "110px" }]
                });
```

And whats coming from server is something like this

```
[ { "TransactionId" : "185492010250010630", "Log" : "Administrator  Super has updated jobdescmanagement on 1/28/2015 4:24:03 PM"}]
```

Its giving error in console is

```
Uncaught Sys.ParameterCountException: Sys.ParameterCountException: Parameter count mismatch.
```

Comment: If you set data: "d" in your schema, then you do not need the column field to have "d". That makes it try to bind to d.d.TransactionId which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your JSON data structure fields configuration should be

```
columns: [{
    field: "TransactionId",
    title: "TransactionID",
    width: "30px"
}, {
    field: "Log",
    title: "Audit Logs",
    width: "110px"
}]
```

in this case you don't need `schema` configuration as you don't have root JSON element.

The schema

```
schema: {
    data: "d"
}
```

implies that data has the following format:

```
{d: [{"TransactionId": "185492010250010630", "Log": "Administrator Super has updated jobdescmanagement on 1/28/2015 4:24:03 PM"}]}
```

however this is not your case.

Comment: no its not fixed after changing column configuration , i've tried this before